# How to refresh the content of the fragments with the navigation component when returning from an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I currently have an activity that implements a bottom nav bar with the navigation component to navigate between 4 fragments.

Right now, one of these fragments opens a new activity and I would like when closing it to refresh the fragment content again, as this happens only when I navigate between the fragments.

Any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I coded the following solution which worked perfectly. I hope it can be useful to someone, best regards!

```
private fun refreshFragment() {
    navController.currentDestination?.id?.let { id ->
        navController.popBackStack(id, inclusive = true)
        navController.navigate(id)
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    refreshCurrentFragment()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used fesave's answer alongside with an implementation of `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener` in my Activity, so as to fire this `refreshFragment()` function - it worked like a charm, with no visible UI lag.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).